# How to change player states?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a "design pattern" problem. I want to enable for a player to change his state. Lets say I have three states or super powers if you will. Each of them have different abilities. If this abilities were just based on some attributes (lets say mass or speed) I could just change that on the player and everything would work fine.

But what if there are some other functionalities changed. Lets say if the player is in the state 2 and he jumps the animation is different and some other thing changes. Now I know I could make this with a lot of checking in update loop for states but I want to make this elegant.

My idea until now is to make generalPlayer object and the each special player inherits from it and adds special abilities, and when player change state I would kind of change instance of player to that instance.

Is there any better way? I am using c# as scripting language

Comment: Have you heard about `State` design pattern? Also, if your states doesn't know about each other, then `Strategy` pattern would also be quite nice. By the way, I also love Unity 3D, if you want we can schedule a pair programming session to help you solve your problem. The question is quite general to answer in text without some details of the project

Comment: I will go check this two patterns. We could totally do that. I am curently working on a simple 2d game.

Comment: my skype is in the profile, feel free to write. I'm learning Unity, also started from 2d games, but I can help with C# code organisation.

Comment: I will send you request. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best suiting sollution thanks to friend. What I use was an Strategy pattern and then put different instances to the interface I used to controll the player. It works like charm. Thanks all for help.

Comment: why not put some pseudo code of your `Strategy` and how you change your player instance type? It would improve a lot your answer, we could discuss improvements and it will help others

Answer (score 1):

The problem I have with that approach is that you are using multiple different objects for one player. There could be some mess involved with passing data every time the player changes states which would be better avoided. Since C# has delegates, which, for our purposes, behave much like first class functions, it is possible to change the behavior of your player by changing out certain routines and field values on every change of state. This allows you to keep your data in one object and change behavior on the fly without relying solely on conditionals. There is a pithy phrase I have heard many times, that an object encapsulates state and behavior. In C#, you can change state by manipulating field values, and change behavior by relying on delegates. That should cover your problem.